# ViewModel and View not getting bound for user control in listbox

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, simple-injector

I have a `BooksListViewModel` & `BooksListView` which have just a list box named `Books` which should be populated via the `BindableCollection<BookViewModel> Books` property in the ViewModel.

Nothing is showing up, and I think either the Book listbox and property aren't being properly bound, or it's the `BookView` and `BookViewModel`, but I can't figure out which.

I'm also using SimpleInjector, and I think it's that I maybe haven't set that up correctly? I copied most of the code from the Caliburn feature samples - specifically from the `Bindings` example.

Code for the bootstrapper:

```
namespace WPFCaliburnUI
{
    public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private Container _container;

        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
// Mostly taken from here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/migrating-to-simple-injector-30-with-caliburn-micro-bootstrap-changes
            this._container = new Container();
            this._container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ThreadScopedLifestyle();

            this._container.RegisterSingleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
            this._container.RegisterSingleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

            this._container.Register<ShellWindowViewModel>();
            this._container.Register<BooksListViewModel>();

            SetupContextAndCrudServices() // Removed this method since it's a little long, 
                                          // but I did verify it is working correctly. 
                                          // Just adds the context and other stuff to the container.

            this._container.Verify();
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<ShellWindowViewModel>();
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
        {
            return new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() };
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return this._container.GetInstance(service);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            IServiceProvider provider = this._container;
            Type collectionType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(service);
            var services = (IEnumerable<object>)provider.GetService(collectionType);
            return services ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>();
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            var registration = this._container.GetRegistration(instance.GetType(), true);
            registration.Registration.InitializeInstance(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

BooksListViewModel:

```
internal class BooksListViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly ICrudServices _service;

    private BookViewModel _selectedBook;

    public BookViewModel SelectedBook {
        get => this._selectedBook;
        set => Set(ref this._selectedBook, value);
    }

    public BooksListViewModel(ICrudServices service)
    {
        this._service = service;
        var booksQuery = _service.ReadManyNoTracked<BookListDto>().Take(10);
        var bcBooks = new Collection<BookViewModel>();
        foreach (var bookDto in booksQuery)
        {
            bcBooks.Add(new BookViewModel(bookDto.Title, bookDto.AuthorsOrdered));
        }
        // I did double check that this worked, Books has 10 items.
        this.Books = new BindableCollection<BookViewModel>(bcBooks);
    }

    public BindableCollection<BookViewModel> Books { get; private set; }
}
```

BooksListView:

```
<Page
    x:Class="WPFCaliburnUI.Views.BooksListView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFCaliburnUI.ViewModels"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="BooksListView"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Name="ContentPanel">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="Books">
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="0,12"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,6,0" Text="Selected:" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="SelectedBook_Title" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

BookViewModel:

```
namespace WPFCaliburnUI.ViewModels
{
    internal class BookViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }

        public BookViewModel(string title, string author)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Author = author;
        }
    }
}
```

BookView:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WPFCaliburnUI.Views.BookView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFCaliburnUI.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="600"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Ellipse
            Grid.Column="0"
            Width="48"
            Height="48"
            Margin="0,0,12,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Fill="DarkBlue" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Title"
                FontSize="16"
                FontWeight="SemiBold" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Author" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Edit:
Some people asked for how `BooksListViewModel` is called, so here is the code from the `ShellWindowViewModel`

```
namespace WPFCaliburnUI.ViewModels
{
    internal class ShellWindowViewModel : Screen
    {
        private readonly Container _container;
        private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;
        private INavigationService navigationService;

        public ShellWindowViewModel(Container container, IWindowManager windowManager)
        {
            this._container = container;
            this._windowManager = windowManager;
        }

        public void RegisterFrame(Frame frame)
        {
            navigationService = new FrameAdapter(frame);

            navigationService.NavigateToViewModel(typeof(BooksListViewModel));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked while debugging that `booksQuery ` has data?

Comment: @Nkosi Yea! Sorry forgot to add that. It does have 10 items, as does `Books`.

Comment: Bind it manually and see if it works. Just to trouble shoot. That way you know it is the framework that is the problem.

Comment: When you hover over the list box do the mouse over highlights show? It would mean that the list is populated but it was not able to bind the views for the items.

Comment: You mean bind `BooksListView` and the ViewModel manually? I actually don't know how to do that.. And no, nothing shows up in the list box, I checked the live tree view but it's empty.

Comment: in the list box bind the items source property `ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"`

Comment: Dang, yea did that but still nothing. I think in that case it's the `BookView` and `BookViewModel` that aren't being bound? The `BookView` never gets initialized it seems, just put a breakpoint after `InitializeComponent()` and it never tripped.

Comment: How you calling BooksListView ?  Paste that code may be the  issue is because of duplicate instances

Comment: Don't the view models need to be public?

Comment: How is your shell view defined? Do you see the BooksListView view? Is the ListBox empty?

Comment: Added the code for the ShellViewModel!

Comment: @JackHughes YEP! Ha, didn't even realize they were internal. Once I switched them to public it works perfectly! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JackHughes I was able to fix it. ViewModels must be public, not internal. Switching everything to public fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I Believe that @Nkosi by 'manually' meant more like creating a new instance of your viewmodel in code behind and setting up as DataContext or creating manual bindings from the XAML side. If you know how to work with dependency injection and IoC containers in general I suppose that you know how to setup datacontext in a proper way if not then just let me know and I will help ya. Anyway if I were on your place I'd setup bindings in xaml like:

```
 <Grid Name="ContentPanel">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name="Books"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

        <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0,12"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,6,0" Text="Selected:" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="SelectedBook_Title" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

If the DataContext of your View has your collection then I wouldn't be worried too much. That should do the job.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! Someone above figured out the issue, the ViewModels should've been public.